# Trying to add to state array throws Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm doing to do is get an array of questions from firebase, and I do get it, just as the console.logs are showing.

The only problem is when I'm trying to add that array to my state "preguntas", which I originally set as null and then changed it to [] thinking it may be that. Also I've tried with concat and other things I found.

One thing I also did, although I don't know if it was for another reason, I tried

```
preguntasRef.on('value', snap => ...
```

just to get the same result. But it could be because of the way I'm trying to set the array into my state.

Basically I don't know if at some point I did get the answer, just implemented it incorrectly, and so I still can't add the info I'm getting from firebase to my state.

(IMAGE UPDATE, previous image didn't have the question keys, as questions are also uploaded from the app).
This is the database in Firebase:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state= {
            preguntas: [],
            ponenteSelect: this.props.match.params.id,
            idOrador: this.props.location.state
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        var preguntasRef = firebase.database().ref(this.state.idOrador).child("preguntas");
        preguntasRef.on('value', this.gotData, this.errData);
        /*preguntasRef.on('value', snap =>{
            this.setState({
                preguntas: snap.val()
            });
        });*/
    }

    gotData(data){
        let preguntasFirebase = data.val();
        console.log(preguntasFirebase);
        if (preguntasFirebase !== null) {
            this.setState({ preguntas: this.state.preguntas.concat(preguntasFirebase)});
            //this.setState({ preguntas: [...this.state.preguntas, ...preguntasFirebase]});

            //console.log(`Json preguntas ${jsonPregs}`);
            /*let keys = Object.keys(preguntas);
            for (let i=0; i<keys.length;i++){
                let k = keys[i];
                let pregunta = preguntas[k].pregunta;
                conjuntoPregs.push(pregunta);
            }*/
        }
    }
    errData(err){
        console.log('Error!', err);
    }
```

As you can see, I tried three main things. The first was with reference.on(vale, snap=>), the second was with just on and a function with a for, and the third, in the same function I just commented the for and did the setState directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor add

```
this.gotData = this.gotData.bind(this)
```

Also I see one more issue please update setState to following (avoid mutation)

```
this.setState({ preguntas: [...this.state.preguntas].concat(preguntasFirebase)});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, just another question. I updated the firebase image, because when there are new questions, each has a key provided by firebase, so I now get: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {-LNLVWCjXTOs6sDsTcM3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I updated in the for, to get each key, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are improperly setting the context for the function that calls `this.setState()` which can be remedied in one of three ways.

## Binding Context

Your function doesn't have a properly bound context that React can use. React extracts the function, so without an implicit context it will be undefined when called. This can be remedied by either using arrow functions in the constructor, or binding it explicitly in the constructor. Another option is to use an arrow function at render, [but this uses more resources in the long run, can cause unexpected behavior and should be avoided](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36).

### Binding in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
        preguntas: [],
        ponenteSelect: this.props.match.params.id,
        idOrador: this.props.location.state
    }
    this.gotData = this.gotData.bind(this); // gives it an explicit this context to be reused
}
```

### Binding with an arrow function in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
        preguntas: [],
        ponenteSelect: this.props.match.params.id,
        idOrador: this.props.location.state
    }
    this.gotData = (data) => {...} // by putting it here it will be bound to the constructor instance it's created in(lexical)
}
```